Project gradle wrapper not being used by jdtls lsp for nvim
I want to use nvim for java 11 development. So, I am using nvim-jdtls plugin. Manually installed an older version of jdtls for java 11 compatibility. However, jdtls is building the project without using project gradlew file which is causing the build to fail. Please help if you know a fix for this.
